# Way to edit word documents via web page

Tags: web-services

I want to implement a way of editing and create new word documents or excel documents via a web browser. I am looking to do something similar to google docs but implement a project management system to the software. All Ideas welcome. 

Dean

Comment: Good Luck with that! It's a big project you want to do here.
You can look at things like TinyMCE or (F)CKEditor to see how word processing engines could be done

Comment: They look cool might be worth just using one of those, however by the looks of it they don't support spreadsheets any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [(F)CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)